# MacBook Pro 2009 won't go to sleep when lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake

My macbook pro 2009 stopped hibernating after closing the lid, also keyboard back light seems stopped working as well, I tried LabTick but no luck.

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
pid 139(coreaudiod): [0x0000008f000101e7] 00:09:05 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.Boom2Engine:0.context.preventuseridlesleep" 
    Created for PID: 348. 
   pid 98(hidd): [0x0000004900090168] 00:10:15 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
    Timeout will fire in 109 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that well-known Mac-borker.. Boom2

`com.apple.audio.Boom2Engine:0.context.preventuseridlesleep`

Uninstall it [your speakers will last longer] or see if there's an update that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin, but it was fine for long time, i had problem with screen and one of the chips on logic board was supposed to be fixed, guy who was dealing with this does not know what happened also my keyboard back light stopped working he suggested that connector was disconnected i will find out on Monday.